# login to fiware GE using putty (Windows) - what credentials?

Tags: ssh, putty, fiware, filab

I have a FiWare GE instance setup, with a security group, key, and IP all configured. I also have Putty setup to allow me to connect to the instance. My problem is that when I connect I get asked for login information. I've tried my login credentials for Fi-Ware but that doesn't work. There are no other users associated, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to use. There doesn't seem to be any (obvious) way to create users and associate them with an application either.

Are there default login credentials I should be aware of? Do I need to make a user specifically for my instance?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's off-topic here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I was instructed by FI-Ware to post questions here, but sure.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PuTTygen` to generate the `.ppk` file to access through `PuTTy` (load your `.pem`, generate the `.ppk` file and save on your harddisk).

With this file, you open `PuTTy`, go to Connection, SSH, Auth and load your `.ppk` file

I hope this can be useful for

Comment: Hi jjmartinez. I've already done that, but when I try to connect I'm still getting asked for a username and password. I've resorted to using MINGW in the meantime.

Comment: Yup, tried that. It then asks for a password and I've no idea what that password is meant to be.

Comment: Without pass. If you are generate correctly the ppk file, you only need to put "root", without password

Comment: To generate the ppk file, only need to load the .pem and then click on "Save private key"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the VM; sometimes 'root' is not the right username. The documentation, sometimes lacks here. If the VM is a Ubuntu base, then 'ubuntu' would be the username.

And as mentioned before, make sure that you have the right 'read' rights for the keys on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It it just a problem about the permissions that you have in the .pem file. You just need to change it to 600 (u+rw only)

```
 chmod 600 <file>.pem
```

And then try to connect again with your ssh client.

```
 ssh -i <file>.pem root@<IP of the VM>
```

Comment: While that does work for me, my question was about using Putty. I'm also using Windows, so chmod isn't applicable. Thank you for your response though!