# Log in to VM in FIWARE Lab using Windows

Tags: ssh, putty, fiware, filab

I'm trying to login to my brand new instance in FIWARE lab without success. I'm trying with Putty and OpenSSH in Windows. So far:

1. Launched the instance while creating a keypair (ubuntu)
2. Assigned the public IP

1st tried with Putty:

1. Saved the private key using the pem file
2. Used it in the login
3. Asked for a user (don't know which one to used but tried both "root" and "ubuntu"
4. Got an error window ("Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key).

2nd tried with OpenSSH
- Used command window
- Changed persmissions chmod -600 *.pem
- Tried to connect with "ssh -i *.pem root@130.206.120.3" and "ssh -i *.pem ubuntu@130.206.120.3"
- Got the error "Permission denied (public key)".

I have checked [login to fiware GE using putty (Windows) - what credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950092/login-to-fiware-ge-using-putty-windows-what-credentials)
and other related entries but no luck.

By the way the Virtual Console opens and asks me for user/password which again do not know.

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards
Miguel.

Comment: Those are Fiware Lab credentials.

Comment: Sorted out!. After several tries with the instance base_ubuntu_16.04 I decided to launch a new one with the base_ubuntu_14.04 and it worked. By the way the user is "ubuntu" not the FIWARE Lab credentials

Comment: Your question is very confused. It seems your problem was not related with fiware, but It was just OS login (Ubuntu) and remote access. Just this.